# Add new column in pyspark data frame comparing two column present in same data frame

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame with two columns COL_1 and COL_2.

[image]

I want to add one more column COL_3 and COL_3 value will depend on the comparison of COL_1 and COL_2 as per below table.

[image]

**When both values same COL_3 = Valid**

**When both values different COL_3 = Invalid**

**When both value the null COL_3 = null**

I tried something below code but it's not working.

`df_Input =  dataframe.withColumn("COL_3", (col("COL_1") != col("COL_1")), lit("Invalid")).otherwise(lit("valid"))`

Comment: You're close. Use `func.when()` and give two criteria, `func.when(col('col_1') == col('col_2'), lit('valid')).when(col('col_1') != col('col_2'), lit('invalid'))`. The `null` will not satisfy any of them and hence will result in `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
```df = df.withColumn('COL_3',\
        when((col("COL_1") == col("COL_2")), 'Valid').\
        when((col("COL_1") != col("COL_2")), 'Invalid').\
        otherwise(lit("NA")))```
````

Here I am first adding one column COL_3 and with the help of *when* function I checked weather COL_1 and COL_2 are equal or differ and I assigned *valid* and *invalid* values to COL_3.
If COL_1 and COL_2 are blank then it will assign *NA* to COL_3.

Answer (score 0):

first will add col3 with default value using `lit` function while reading CSV file

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","|").load('test.csv').withColumn('COL_3',lit('Invalid'))
```

now will check the condition using `when` function

```
df = df.withColumn('COL_3', when((col("COL_1") == col("COL_1")), 'Valid').when((col("COL_1") == 'null') & (col("COL_2" == 'null')),'null').otherwise(col('COL_3')))
```

Comment: What happens if both the column values have `null`?

Comment: I added null condition as well.

Comment: @samkart is right, no need to use otherwise, or create col3 at read.

Comment: df = df.withColumn('COL_3', when((col("COL_1") == col("COL_2")), 'Valid').when((col("COL_1") != col("COL_2")), 'Invalid').otherwise(lit("null"))).....I am trying this

Comment: @aamirmalik124 null values in spark are denoted by None, not string of "null", that is unless your dataframe nulls are specified to be strings of "null".

Comment: @aamirmalik124 your code without the otherwise should suffice, unless you need to force ur nulls to be of stringtype'null'

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi df = df.withColumn('COL_3', when((col("COL_1") == col("COL_2")), 'Valid').when((col("COL_1") != col("COL_2")), 'Invalid').otherwise(lit("NA"))).....I think now it is useful.

Comment: @aamirmalik124 why would you want to put string of "NA" to denote your nulls. use otherwise(lit(None)))

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi  In future I want o use it in groupby and in filter.